# Fill missing value with conditional binary indicator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am looking for way to fill the missing value with 1 or 0 based on condition evaluating another feature variable.

Simplified form of dataset:

```
**Show       Time_watched    Completed**
GOT             400            1
The Office     424            1
Breaking Bad    325            0
GOT             325            0
The Office      344            NaN
Breaking Bad    325            1
```

I want to fill missing value with condition that:
If Time_watched is greater than average/third quantile time_watched for the show, fill with 1 else 0

In this above example, to fill NaN in completed column, ideally function should compare 344mins with average Time_watched of “The office” show and decide either to insert 1 or 0.

I am trying different combination of fillna, groupby, transform and lambda functions but I am not able to generate desired Output.
Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mean_val = df.groupby("Show")["Time_watched"].transform("mean")
df["Completed"] = (
    df["Completed"].fillna((df["Time_watched"] > mean_val)).astype(int)
)
```

Output:

```
           Show  Time_watched  Completed
0           GOT           400          1
1    The Office           424          1
2  Breaking Bad           325          0
3           GOT           325          0
4    The Office           344          0
5  Breaking Bad           325          1
```

First, calculate the mean by show using `groupby` with `transform` then, compare that each value, and `fillna`.

---

Quantile 75%

```
q75 = df.groupby("Show")["Time_watched"].transform(pd.Series.quantile, q=.75)
df['Complete'] = df["Completed"].fillna((df["Time_watched"] > q75)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
           Show  Time_watched  Completed  Complete
0           GOT           400        1.0         1
1    The Office           424        1.0         1
2  Breaking Bad           325        0.0         0
3           GOT           325        0.0         0
4    The Office           344        NaN         0
5  Breaking Bad           325        1.0         1
```

Comment: Edited the code with `black` to make it in accordance with `PEP-8`. Feel free to revert if not okay.

Comment: I like black.... are you using it in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: No from the terminal. I wrote a script which dumps contents from clipboard to a `.py` and I pass that file to `black`

Comment: Thanks Chester, is there way to make comparison with 75th percentile of value in transform?